# Why is the boolean value within a structure within a vector not being updated?

Tags: c++, c++11

This might sound like a very basic question, but I have trying to fix a simple bug for over an hour now and I can't seem to understand what's happening.

I have the following structure declaration in my header file:

```
struct StudentBody
{
    string name;

    Vec2 position;

    bool disabled;

    StudentBody(string name, Vec2 position) : name(name), position(position) {}
};
```

This structure is being filled into a vector of type:

```
std::vector<StudentBody> students_real;
```

Like this:

```
students_real =
    {
        StudentBody("student1",Vec2(DISPLAY_WIDTH - 50, LOWER_MARGIN + 100)),
        StudentBody("student2",Vec2(DISPLAY_WIDTH - 100, LOWER_MARGIN + 100)),
        StudentBody("student3",Vec2(DISPLAY_WIDTH - 150, LOWER_MARGIN + 100)),
        StudentBody("student4",Vec2(DISPLAY_WIDTH - 200, LOWER_MARGIN + 100))
    };
```

By default all of the students have their "disabled" set to false.

Then I have an "update" method that gets triggered with the screen refresh rate, and within that method I have the following code:

```
for (auto it = students_real.begin(); it != students_real.end(); it++)
        {
            auto student_to_check = *it;

            CCLOG("student %s disabled -> %i",student_to_check.name.c_str(),student_to_check.disabled);

            if (student_to_check.name == "student1" || student_to_check.disabled) {
                continue;
            }

            bool disableStudent = true;

            //... A custom condition here checks if "disabledStudent" should become false or stay as true...

            if (disableStudent)
            {
                CCLOG("Disabling %s",student_to_check.name.c_str());

                student_to_check.disabled = true;

                CCLOG("student %s disabled -> %i",student_to_check.name.c_str(),student_to_check.disabled);
            }
        }
```

The problem here is that the "disabled" flag is not staying as true. When I check the condition at first it's false. Then I check my second condition too and if it's satisfied I set it to true. However the next time this for loop is started the condition is back to false.

This makes me believe that my `"auto student_to_check = *it;"` gives me a copy of the structure to handle it but not the structure itself? Or what is going on? Why can't I modify the value of the structure within the vector?

Comment: `auto student_to_check = *it` => `auto& student_to_check = *it`

Comment: need to be `auto& student_to_check = *it;`

Comment: Your constructor for `StudentBody` does not guarantee that "by default all of the students have their "disabled" set to false"

Comment: You could also use a range-based for loop, like: `for(auto&& student_to_check : students_real)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
auto student_to_check = *it;
```

declares a local variable that is a copy of the structure in the vector.  The iterator points to the structure in the vector, so you can use:

```
auto student_to_check = it;
```

and:

```
student_to_check->disabled = true;
```

or more simply the following to access anything in the vector's structure.  Then you don't need the local variable:

```
it->disabled = true;
```

Even better would be to use C++11's range-based for loop, as @sp2danny commented:

```
for(auto& student_to_check : students_real)
```

`student_to_check` will reference the structure in the vector instead of a local copy, and the rest of your code remains as is.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, I actually had for(auto student_to_check : students_real) at first but i was having the same behavior so I changed it to using iterators. Was it because i was missing the "&", Is the default behavior for auto on structures to make a copy and auto& to make a pointer?  For Objects using auto is enough right? since objects are already pointers.

Comment: @Chiquis, yes, without `&` the `for` is making a copy of the object.  Adding `&` makes `student_to_check` a reference to the original object.

Comment: I have another structure which is "Vector<Student *> students;" this is with capital V because its a custom cocos2dx vector but its basically the same as std::vector, in this case  "for (auto it = Student::students.begin(); it != Student::students.end(); it++) {  auto student = *it; //...modifying code...  } is correct right? (If i want to modify it, Since its a vector of pointers and not of structures)

Comment: yes, or again use the range-based for loop: `for(auto student : students)`.  This time making a copy of the pointer is fine.

Comment: Ah thank you so much for your help, you've help me understand how it works. I can't use a ranged-based for loop because im using the iterator to delete the element under a certain condition, but you've sold my issue, thanks!

Comment: when you are deleting certain items, be sure to do it the idiomatic way, ie `if(shouldDelete) it=students.erase(it); else ++it;` and don't update `it` in the for-loop